# Command Line Calulator, Java

Tags: java

Input from the Java commandline: "4 + 6 + 5 - 5".
Wanted outcome: "is 10".
Actual outcome: "is 5".

```
class Calculator
{
    int v_in1, v_in2, v_in3, v_in4, v_answer, result;
    String v_sign1, v_sign2, v_sign3;

    public Calculator()
    {
    }



    public void count(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            //System.out.print(args[i]+ " ");

            if(i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
            {   
                v_in1 = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                //System.out.print(v_in1 + " ");
            }

            switch(args[i])
            {
                case "+": {
                    v_answer += v_in1;
                    break;
                }
                case "-": {
                    v_answer -= v_in1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("is " + v_answer);
    }

}
```

There might be some additional problems *e.g* too many variable declared etc, but what I'm concerned about it the for- if- switch part, I'm unable to pin- point the problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: This is because the last argument will not be added since it will not fall in the switch case on the last iteration

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your logic is applying the operator to the previous value. So you are adding 4 (to get 4), adding 6 (to get 10) subtracting 5 (to get 5) then ignoring the second 5 as it has no operator. I assume this is not what you're after.

Comment: As a side note, `0 % 2 == 0` is `true`, so your if statement could just be `i % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying the operation to the *previous* number, not to the next to come. Instead you should memorize the operator and update the result when you see a number, e.g. like this:

```
int sign = +1, result = 0;
for (String arg : args) {
    switch (arg) {
        case "+":
            sign = +1;
            break;
        case "-":
            sign = -1;
            break;
        default:
            result += sign * Integer.parseInt(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your last integer wont be taken into account as it is just stored in v_in1, but since there is no +,- so it doesnt get added or subtracted. Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.print(args[i]+ " ");

        if(i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
        {   
            v_in1 = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            //System.out.print(v_in1 + " ");


        }


        switch(args[i])
        {
            case "+":
            {
                v_answer = v_in1 + Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]) + v_answer;
                i++;   

            break;
            }
            case "-":
            {

                v_answer = v_in1 - Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]) + v_answer;
                i++;
            break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hy, thanks for all the answers. Really liked Tobias_K's answer, although for some reason it didn't run on the exercise environment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know all requirements for this task, but I recommend to convert the [whole expression to postfix notation](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/infix-postfix/), then parse it using stack to [evaluate the result](http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/).

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your method, and I recommend you simplify your code (something like this for `long count(String[] args)`)

```
long result = 0; // Note, this shadows your Object's result. I'm not sure why you
                 // had hard-coded fields like that. I don't think you need them.
                 // Also, this returns a long.
boolean negative = false;
for (String arg : args) {
  String oper = arg.trim();
  if (oper.equals("+")) { // Is it a plus sign?
    negative = false;
  } else if (oper.equals("-")) { // Is it a minus sign?
    negative = !negative; // - a negative value is addition
  } else {
    try {
      int i = Integer.parseInt(oper); // Parse the integer
      if (negative) {
        i = -i;
        negative = false;
      }
      result += i; // add the result
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      System.err.println(oper + " is not +, - or a number");
    }
  }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is what worked in the exercise.*

```
class Calculator
{

int v_answer = 0;
int v_in1 = 0;


public Calculator()
{

}

public void count(String args[])
{

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Result of the calculation ");

    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(args[i]+ " ");

        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {   
            v_in1 = Integer.parseInt(args[i]); 
        }

        if(i == 0)
        {
            v_answer += Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }


        if(args[i].equals("+"))
        {   

            v_answer += Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]); 

        }
        else if(args[i].equals("-"))
        {
            v_answer  -=  Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);

        }


    }

    System.out.print("is " + v_answer);
    System.out.println();
}
```

}